# how to get button value after button clicked

Tags: php, magento-2.1.8

I'm trying to get the value of a button when it is clicked, because I got multiple buttons depending on how much data I got. So I need to know which button did I click. I got the code for the button like below.

```
<button type="submit" data-multiship-item-update="" class="action split" data-role="split" data-flag="0" value ="<?php echo $index ?>" <?php if ($reduce >= (int)$item->getQty()):?> disabled="disabled" <?php endif; ?>><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Add item(s) to Address') ?></span></button>
```

So the question is, how can I get the **value** of the button when I click it?

Comment: are you want using jquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer my self by adding **name** to the button, and get the value by **getPost("button name")** in the controller like code below.

Button :

```
 <button type="submit" name="btn" data-multiship-item-update="" class="action split" data-role="split" data-flag="0" value ="<?php echo $index ?>" <?php if ($reduce >= (int)$item->getQty()):?> disabled="disabled" <?php endif; ?>><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Add item(s) to Address') ?></span></button>
```

Controller :

```
$btn = $this->getRequest()->getPost('btn');
```